# Google Hangouts link in event descriptions

Tags: php, gmail, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I use a PHP iCal library to import ics URLs from gmail. Everything worked fine until Friday (19th of January). Hangouts links are now included in the description of the events. I've read that there is a setting in the Google Admin console to disable automatic video calls but we can't ask each and everyone of our clients to go and disable this option. What is the easiest way to strip out these links? Keep in mind it's not only a URL. Also the text might appear in different languages.

*This event has a Google Hangouts video call.
 Join: https://plus.google.com/hangouts/...*

Does this have anything to do with the new Calendar app that Google launched recently?

Comment: `$pos = strpos($sentence, 'This event has a Google Hangouts video call.');
if($pos !== false) {
 echo substr($sentence, 0, $pos);
}`

From what I saw the Hangouts part is always appended to the description. In other words whatever the user inputted into the description box, will be first.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling the "Automatically add video calls to events created by a user" setting is the first step in solving this problem (per https://support.google.com/a/answer/6188027?hl=en).

However, it doesn't get rid of Hangout links in existing calendar events.  I have multiple calendars going back over 15 years with thousands of events, and I noticed that even old events were filled with Hangouts links.  Manually unchecking the Hangouts box in the Calendar web interface was not practical.

After searching far and wide, I found the [Bulk Edit Calendar Events](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-yn3tLZC0zWv3e4sKgFY99FL3mJjUT9qh2yFBFcUrkI/edit#gid=1639798387) spreadsheet(?)/script that looked like it might be a good starting point to do this, but I was unable to get this to delete the Hangouts links (the script interface used there apparently does not allow modifying Hangouts on the calendar).

After contacting the author, he wrote a new script [Remove Hangouts from events](https://script.google.com/d/1PdvzZWFemGqCKG2wgP4BWKYrVAi2_PHDCaig0yK-BA13Qkusl8xelI56/edit?usp=sharing) with a lower-level Calendar API (link is to my somewhat modified version), that removes *only* the Hangouts from each of the matching Calendar events.  This needs to be imported into your Google space and run there (modifying the events from iCal doesn't get rid of the Hangout link), edited to set parameters, and authorized to run.

I'm leery of running unknown scripts with access to my Google account, but is short and simple enough to review that it is clearly doing what it should.

Answer (score 0):

You have to ask users to disable it on their settings. It's what's stated in the support page:

> [Disable automatic video calls in Google
>   Calendar](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6188027?hl=en)
>
> By
>   default, video calls are automatically added to all Google Calendar
>   events.
>
> Administrators can disable this setting. Users must then manually
>   click Add a video call every time a Google Calendar event is created.
>
> To change the setting:
>
> Sign in to the Google Admin console. Click Apps > G Suite > Calendar.
>   Click Sharing settings. Under Video Calls, uncheck Automatically add
>   video calls to events created by a user.